# Data fitting ( equation given but don't know how to use them ) in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have to fit the data of a given equation to other data in the blue line shown in picture attached.

[image: picture with data]

The initial values for r and c are 0.004 and 40 respectively.  The result values for r and c will be 0.0068 and 54.23 respectively. The equation are provided below.

I am not getting the fit graph. I don't know where I am making a mistake. Red circles are I think my fitting result.  Here is my working on Matlab.

**Function file:**

```
function y = FOM2(t,r,c)

    t=(0:0.01:2);
    q=zeros(1,length(t));

    for i=1:length(t)

        if (t(i) < 1)
           q(i) = 600;
        else
           q(i) = 0;
        end

        y= q*(r+(1/c));

    end
```

**Error value function:**

```
function error=RCvalues(x,time,data)

    r = x(1); c = x(2);
    test = FOM2(time,r,c);
    d= data - test;
    error = sum(d.^2);
```

**Fitting file:**

```
Data = load ('Paw.txt'); %Load measurement data
Time = load ('time.txt');
Data=data';
Time=ime';

opt = optimset('MaxFunEvals',10000,'TolFun',1e-6);
x = fminsearch(@(x) RCvalues(x,Time,Data),[0.004 40],opt);

r = x(1);
c = x(2);

yy= FOM2(Time,r,c);

fprintf('Final values:\n');
fprintf('r %7.3f\n',x(1));
fprintf('c %7.3f\n',x(2));

plot(Time,Data)
hold on
plot(Time,yy,'o');
```

Here are the equations,

```
totaltime is 2 sec

dPalv/dt=q/c

Paw= r*q+palv
```

I have to use Paw equation but don't know how.

Comment: The fit obtained by fminsearch is correct because the function you are trying to fit the data to is essentially a step function. The part about Paw equation is completely unrelated, it seems that even you don't know how to use the equation then how do you expect others to understand how these equations fit in your problem. Also, this sounds like a homework problem.

Comment: I am new to matlab, the class practices include equation which have time in them but this paw equation i have to fit this is my task . I want to know hot to fit time in paw equation.

Comment: May be you could post your assignment and the data sets to let us understand the problem better?